# Excel Office 365: 'not equal to' doesn't work in advanced filter

Tags: excel, office365

I have a database and use Advanced filter to extract requiered data. Technically it works fine, that is, when the criteria are like this:

[image]

But when I change Criteria3 to <>40010, like this:

[image]

I get the correct data, <> 40010 from Criteria3, but still also data that meet the first Criteria3 =40010. I've tried every combination of the 3 criteria I could think of, and all was well as long I didn't use <>. Which I don't understand. Could someone please help me with this?

This is an edit answering the question from Louis: "The condition that you entered in the criteria cell, we only see the result of the formula."

This is what works:

[image]

And this is what doesn't work:

[image]

Is this what you ment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <>40010 instead of ="<>40010"

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, can you add details of the actual cell data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I try <>40010 instead of ="<>40010" I get the message Typing error. I believe using the quotation marks is how it should be done. Imho the problem is not those marks, but the operator <>.

Comment: At @Louis. I'm not sure that I understand what you mean with 'actual cell data'. Is that the database that I extract data from?

Comment: @PeterEZ The condition that you entered in the criteria cell, we only see the result of the formula.

Comment: .@Louis I have edited my OP answering your question I hope.

Comment: @PeterEZ, thanks for the clarification. In General the quote "" are only required when the condition start with an = sign for advanced filter. It differentiate it from a formula. However they are not required when used with other operator such as > or <. I tried both version and they both work, but may be there is something there if your version of excel in not the same as mine. Give it a try, it may make a difference.

Comment: '@Louis, thanks for you reply. I'll try what you're suggesting, and I'll be back, hopefully to inform you and others that it works.

Comment: .@Louis, I'm afraid that without the quote "", that is <>40010 instead of ="<>40010" doesn't work either, I stil get data that meet the criteria =40010. Further, when I use this criteria =">40010" (or >40010) I get no data at all, which is nog correct. A bit weard...

Comment: @PeterEZ Can you add an example of the data and result you are getting with these different scenario. May be it has to do with the data format.

Comment: '@Louis Thank you. You may be right about the data format. Yesterday I copied everything on this subject from Microsoft Help to Excel, and with operators like < and <> the equal sign wasn't necessary. After that I tested the data that are part of the criteria with @isnumber, and the result was False. Your previous explanation "In General the quote "" are only required when the condition start with an = sign for advanced filter." gave me the inspiration to do this. Thanks. I'll change the data format to 'number' and try the advanced filter again. Then I'll be back.

Comment: After having changed the format of the criteria to 'number' the advcanced filter worked fine. So I think the problem is solved. Thanks @Louis.